# Plugin: How do I set default value into an attribute depending business unit?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have 3 business units (1 parent and 2 children), 3 users (for each business unit), 2 forms (for each business unit) and 1 plugin for the incident entity.

The incident plugin (create, pre-operation) is setting a default value in the attribute 'Case Origin' (caseorigincode) depending on user's business unit.

My problem is what if the user of the parent business unit creates an incident? how the plugin knows from which form that incident is created to set the default value?

What is the best approach to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way for the plugin to know which form was submitted. However, you could add a hidden field that gets set via javascript to something different for each form. Then, in the plugin you could query that field to see which form was used.

Be sure to check for null/empty as well, because the update could have been submitted programmatically without the use of a form.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC all CRM entities (both stock and custom) should have a `OwningBusinessUnit` attribute which is an `EntityReference` to the Business Unit the record's `Owner` belongs to.

That should tell you exactly from which BU the record is being created.

(NOTE: The question is inconsistent, since it is stated that caseorigincode is set depending on the BU at first, then it asks about forms. I assume the first is the actual logic: check the BU to set the field)

(NOTE #2: This could be accomplished through a workflow aswell: `Check Condition` on Owner's BU and `Update Record` accordingly. Run on create.)

Answer (score 0):

Given a user can only be a member of one business unit then you shouldn't need to worry about which form it was created in.  Simply get the `SystemUser` from the `EntityReference` of the created by user and use the `BusinessUnit` `EntityReference` that provides you with.